# Using font-size:15px - will it cause any problems?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-size

This sounds like a silly question and it probably is but I'm building a website on top of Bootstrap and it uses 14px font size as a default. There is a lengthy discussion of various font sizes / line heights [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/724) but only **16px** is mentioned as a possibly better value than 14px, *never* 15px.

When testing my site, 14px looks too small and 16px too big. 15px seems like a sweet spot but it is so rarely used that it leaves me wondering whether it might possibly cause some issues later on? Or is it just a matter of preference that most people decide between 14px and 16px and ignore 15px?

Comment: You should choose a font-size that is readable for the font face you are using, that's all

Comment: This is probably better for http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry if this sounded like a question about perception. I meant to aks whether there are technical reasons why is 15px so often avoided. I have updated the question.

Comment: This is a technical question not necessarily UX and def *not* opinion.  Most quality computer fonts have specific designs for specific point sizes, like 14 and 16. Other sizes are some form of scale or interpolation. Some fonts even have direct bitmaps or super heavy hinting to generate specific bitmaps to look as crisp as possible at 96 dpi with lower sizes like 12 14 and 16.  There are fonts that only have one vector version for each glyph and have real issues at lower sizes on a computer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd imagine 16px and 14px are just preference given that they divide easier than odd numbers. If say you were to use em instead of px later on and wanted something to be .5 em or .25em, 14 and 16 px divides nicely compared to 15px. This may cause problems when those ems are converted back to pixels later on, but I don't think it would be much of an issue

Comment: It also depends on the `font-family` you are using. For example when I use `Proxima-Nova` with `font-size: 15px`, the dots above the letter "i" become illegible and make it look like an "l". Using 14px or 16px though is fine.